# Pre-fill Subject Text Field / Form with Mailboxer Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

In my application I have a Listing page where Users can display their products.

Other users can contact the Author of Listing.

I have created a message button on Listing Page that once clicked the page is redirected to Mailboxer form and the Recipient text field is prefilled. I would like the Subject to fill with the text from Title of Listing.

My code:

```
module MessagesHelper

  # This is the helper for grabbing a User
  def recipients_options(chosen_recipient = nil)
    s = ''
    User.all.each do |user|
      s << "<option value='#{user.id}' #{'selected' if user == chosen_recipient}>#{user.name}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end

  # This is the helper for grabbing the Title from Listing
  def recipient_subject(chosen_subject = nil)
    s = ''
    Listing.all.each do |subject|
    s << "<option value='#{subject.id}' #{'selected' if subject == chosen_subject}>#{subject.title}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end
end
```

my Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  # before_action :correct_user

  def new
    @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]

    @chosen_subject = Listing.find_by(title: params[:title].to_i) if params[:title]
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

end
```

my view

Listing > Show (the button to contact)

```
<p>
  <strong>Contact Seller about "<%= @listing.title %>"</strong></br>
  <%= link_to "Send message to #{@listing.user.name}", new_message_path(to: @listing.user.id, message: @listing.title), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
</p>
```

and finally my new Message form

```
<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :post do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Subject' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', recipient_subject, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Message' %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
    <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

With this code all the titles display for Listing in the subject field:

`<option value='5' >New Samsung</option><option value='4' >Title</option><option value='3' >New listing</option><option value='2' >Something</option><option value='1' >Disco</option>`

I would like the title for that single listing to appear, but it's not working for me; it's displaying all and with option and value code. Thanks in advance for any help!